# Vuetify - Custom data table - Potential infinite loop: exceeded 10001 iterations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

As the default Vuetify [v-data-table](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/) component doesn't have a numbered **pagination** and **select page dropdown** built-in, I decided to make my own wrapper component, `genericTable.vue`.

Everything is looking the way I want. However, I encounter the following issue:

[image: Potential infinite loop: exceeded 10001 iterations.]

> Note: I want the **genericTable** component to be a dumb component,
> meaning it accepts props and emits events to allow them to be dynamic
> and reusable. As soon as a user selects a page or changes the items per page, an event is emitted
> from the genericTable component to the parent component.

### Sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-frog-rb2v8

### Snippet

```js
// genericTable.vue

<genericTable
    :page="currentPage"
    :pageNumbers="pageNumbers"
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
    :totalItems="totalItems"
    :pageCount="pageCount"
    :itemsPerPage="itemsPerPage"
    @update:page="pageUpdated"
    @update:itemsPerPage="itemsPerPageUpdated">
</genericTable>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i saw, your problem is computed property `pageCount`, I replaced `this.items.length` with `itemsPerPage`

```
pageCount() {
      return Math.ceil(this.totalItems / this.itemsPerPage) || 0;
    },
```

If `items` were less than your `itemsPerPage` they return miscalculation.
To show the last page in codesandbox, also you need to request the correct size of items

```
      let size = this.itemsPerPage;
      // For last page, if our request size is more than totalItems
      // we need to return totalItems % itemsPerPage
      if(this.itemsPerPage * this.currentPage > this.totalItems )
        size = this.totalItems % this.itemsPerPage;
      this.fetchPassengers(this.currentPage, size);
```